# How to determine database type? (two files each table, compressed with zlib)

Tags: database, file, compression, zlib

I'm trying to determine type of database files from one application. I don't know much about the application, only that it **is** a desktop application for Windows platform and it **is not** an open-source.

## So far I know this:

### File names

*[tablename].MBJ, [tablename].M*

Each table has these two files.

### File format

All files are compressed by zlib (www.zlib.net) and it can be decompressed (whole files).

### Decompressed files

1/ It's binary files.

2/ When I open those files, I can read some texts in it, but it's binary, so it doesn't have any structure I could use for read those data.

***.MBJ files**

1/ These are the smaller ones.

**Compressed sizes:**

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  15K pro 12 15:40 ***.MBJ
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  13K pro 12 15:40 ***.MBJ
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1,4K pro 12 15:40 ***.MBJ
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5,8K pro 12 15:40 ***.MBJ
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  25K pro 12 15:40 ***.MBJ
```

**Decompressed sizes:**

```
-rwx------ 1 fix fix 320K pro 12 15:52 ***.mbj
-rw-r--r-- 1 fix fix 320K pro 12 15:52 ***.mbj
-rw-r--r-- 1 fix fix 256K pro 12 15:52 ***.mbj
-rw-r--r-- 1 fix fix 272K pro 12 15:52 ***.mbj
-rw-r--r-- 1 fix fix 256K pro 12 15:52 ***.mbj
```

There are a lot of zeroes in some of those files.

2/ All of them starts with HEX:

```
00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00
00
```

... and continues with anything (no similarities).

3/ I think of it like index or some helper files (only guess).

***.M files**

1/ These are the bigger ones.

**Compressed sizes:**

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5,1M pro 12 15:40 ***.M
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  14M pro 12 15:40 ***.M
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  26K pro 12 15:40 ***.M
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6,8M pro 12 15:40 ***.M
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 669K pro 12 15:40 ***.M
```

**Decompressed sizes:**

```
-rwx------ 1 fix fix  63M pro 12 15:52 ***.m
-rw-r--r-- 1 fix fix  58M pro 12 15:52 ***.m
-rw-r--r-- 1 fix fix 5,9M pro 12 15:52 ***.m
-rw-r--r-- 1 fix fix  16M pro 12 15:52 ***.m
-rw-r--r-- 1 fix fix 5,7M pro 12 15:52 ***.m
```

2/ It always starts with the file path like

```
d : \ *  * * * *  * * * .  m
```

... folowed by zeroes to the offset of 00000200, column 1 and continues with anything (no similarities).

3/ I think of it like data files due it's sizes.

Anyone knows about some database library which behavior is the same or similar like this one?

Many thanks for help.

Comment: I seem to have the same problem as you - a closed-source application with this kind of files. Did you manage to get anywhere?

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't. We used XML exports which means we need to run the app. I think it's a) some really old database library or b) their own database design. How about you? Did you get anywhere?

Comment: Try trID - sometime it helps.